# Why were these comment not unfriendly or unkind or rude or condescending and flags rejected?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments, code-of-conduct

How are some of the comments on [What to expect from that alternator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395893/what-to-expect-from-that-alternator) not rude, unfriendly or unkind per the new code of conduct https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct? Why were the flags on them declined?

> Apology not accepted. Fix it. There is no excuse. No, I'm not going to tilt my head upside down. Closing as unclear, and -1 for not just fixing the problem. – Olin Lathrop 10 hours ago
>
> (Sorry for the wrong image orientation) You should also apologize for asking a question that is unanswerable. It's like me asking you if you like my Aunt's cooking. You know nothing about my Aunt same as we know basically nothing about this alternator. How do you expect anyone to be able to give a decent answer? – Bimpelrekkie 10 hours ago
>
> "The type id on the plate would make it unambiguously answerable." This is an ironic (and somewhat of a hypocritical) statement. Then why ask us in the first place? Also, it is hard to interpret the this identification because I can't tell if that's a B or an 8, or if that says 65 at the end, etc. Admittedly, to expect us to clearly see every little detail on this picture and to not tell us any numbers that you see on this seems rather unreasonable and arrogant. – KingDuken 10 hours ago

Comment: What's unfriendly here?  Could you clarify, please.

Comment: When the goal posts got moved from to quote CMs `Let’s shift  from “don’t be an asshole” to “be welcoming.” Many people don’t realize that we already have a code of conduct (cuz we gave it a funny name). Or that it already includes concepts like “belittling language is not okay” and “Be welcoming, be patient, … and don’t expect new users to know all the rules — they don’t.”` how about you tell me how those are friendly comments.

Comment: @NickAlexeev `Let’s do something about comments. Condescension and sarcasm have been reluctantly tolerated in comments for too long. We’ll research possible feature changes, but let’s start by working with the community and our community managers to start flagging and deleting unkind comments now.` https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: In your own words.  **You** have raised the issue.  **You** explain it.

Comment: That's not how it works, I am not here to answer your demands. But I am glad you think Stack overflow employee words don't count.

Comment: Well then...  If you can't explain you point.  Or you refuse to explain your point.  Then you don't have a point.  Good night.

Comment: Your condescending sarcasm is well note.

Comment: I don't know if you have time, but please read this thing: [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow).  It's an awesome meta post.

Comment: My flag was recently rejected on: 'Wave a dead fish over a catalog and pick whatever part it drips on first. – Olin Lathrop Sep 9 at 18:44'.  How this is constructive, friendly, etc. is beyond me.?

Comment: @Nick Apparently, [CM disagreed with you](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395893/what-to-expect-from-that-alternator#comment970237_395893): "*Many comments here exemplified the type of behavior that our code of conduct actively discourages, and have been removed. If you feel this question isn't answerable, you have the ability to express that through voting.*"

Comment: @theNamesCross  That comment was under a particularly poor question, which deserved some humor.  The question was also closed, downvoted, on it's way to the StackExchange's automatic cleanup machine.  Iirc.

Answer (score 3):

I've flagged one comment as "not nice" after the rollout of the new guidelines.  The flag was declined, but the comment disappeared nonetheless, which I suppose is the goal.

I suppose the mods thus dealt with the issue, but some clarity on how such issues are handled would be welcome.

Comment: Certain amount of irony here -- years before the "not nice" guidance, I had flagged a comment as abusive, and it was from the OP!!  This, and the comment described in this answer, are my only two declined comment flags.

Comment: Yeah, I've been known to type the wrong thing, and flags on those comments would be totally appropriate. I try to bite my tongue more now.